# Mounting a samba share

Tags: samba, virtualization, hyper-v

I am trying to mount a samba share permanently using Ubuntu as a guest OS in Hyper-V, I have set up a local area connection (through virtual switch and I can ping it's address), however when trying to mount the folder in Ubuntu I get the following error, `Unable to find suitable address`. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Also, why did you choose the "ubuntu-tweak" tag for your question? Is it related to your issue? (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Managed to resolve the problem, instead of trying to use samba share via cifs-utils, I simply created a share on Windows then on Ubuntu machine I accessed the share through "Other networks ” much like Network locations in Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did

Created a folder to share, on Windows named it Ubuntu-Windows share.

[image: Windows shared folder]

Right clicked the folder and selected the share tab.

[image: Sharing options]

Added users and permissions.

[image: Owner perm]

Opened Hyper-V Ubuntu machine, opened the file manager and chose Network.

From there the process is straight-forward, clicked **Connect to Server** entered Host Ip address and entered login details;

[image: Connection via guest os]

Now can easily transfers file from Host-Guest vice versa:

Syncing in Host OS

[image: Sync]

and in Guest OS

[image: Guest sync]

That's all!